# Charting the results of an experiment

Tags: anylogic

I am very new to `ANYLOGIC`. I am trying to use a chart to display the number of operating turbines from the Wind Turbine Tutorial.
I have followed the procedure in the `Anylogic in 3 Days` book and have the following error:

> "Operating cannot be resolved or is not a field" in the statistics field.

I am using the condition `item.inState(turbines.Operating)`. This should count all the agents in the population "turbines" that are in the state `Operating`.
My state chart for the Agent Turbine has 4 states and `Operating` is one of them.

Is there another way of getting this information or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

turbines is a population, so a state is not a part of the population, but a part of either one individual of the population, or the class of the population

so you would need to do

```
item.inState(Turbine.Operating)
```

where Turbine is the Agent Type